# Unexpected use of 'confirm' no-restricted-globals

Tags: reactjs

I am writing code for the delete confirmation for the user, but when I run it up it shows this error
[image]

This is my code for that

```
    onDelete = (id) => {
      console.log(id);
      if (confirm('You want to delette ?')) {
       //eslint-disable-line
        this.props.onDelete(id);
      }
    };
```

Can anyone explain it to me, Please? Although I have to add `//eslint-disable-line` but it does not work, my problem in here is when I add `//eslint-disable-line` beside `if (confirm('You want to delette ?')) {` like this

```
`if (confirm('You want to delette ?')) {//eslint-disable-line`
```

but when I save it, it show like this

```
if (confirm('You want to delette ?')) {
       //eslint-disable-line
```

, it automatically down the line, so that the reason display error above, I do not know how to **turn of the auto down line** when I save

Comment: You can `// eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals` *above* the line, or use `window.confirm` as answered blow.

Comment: @DrewReese works like a charm

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You have to use `window.confirm()` instead of just `confirm()`.

Comment: It may still complain even when doing window.confirm()

Comment: Why was this decision made tho?

Answer (score 17):

You can change this part:

```
if (confirm('You want to delette ?')) {
       //eslint-disable-line
        this.props.onDelete(id);
      }
    };
```

to:

```
if (window.confirm('You want to delette ?')) {
       //eslint-disable-line
        this.props.onDelete(id);
      }
    };
```

Just add window.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable this error by adding `eslint` comment above the confirm() method.

```
onDelete = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
  if (confirm('You want to delete ?')) {
   //eslint-disable-line
    this.props.onDelete(id);
  }
};
```

or you can replace the confirm method with `window.confirm()`

```
onDelete = (id) => {
  console.log(id);
  if (window.confirm('You want to delete ?')) {
   //eslint-disable-line
    this.props.onDelete(id);
  }
};
```